# Getting Error While Loading Custom DLL in Load Runner

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have created one custom DLL for load runner in Visual Studio 2015. When i am loading the DLL in load runner in the machine where i have created it,DLL is loading fine without any error. But when i am loading the custom DLL in Load Runner on different machine(Other than where the DLL has been created) it is throwing "Load Library Failed" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have built your DLL in *Release Win32* configuration: *Debug*-built binaries won't work on machines without Visual Studio 2015 installed (of course, if you don't use Static CRT), while *x64* binaries are not supported by LoadRunner yet. [image]

Also you could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check whether all libraries your DLL depend on are present on the target machine.